# How to pass Observable data to PDF (pdfMake) in Ionic angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, pdfmake

I'm using pdfMake to generate PDF from observable data but it returns empty or [object Object] in the PDF.
Here is my code:

```
downloadPDF() {
  pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

  var docDefination = {
    content: [
      {
        text: "lightHorizontalLines:",
        fontSize: 14,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 8],
      },
      {
        style: "tableExample",
        table: {
          headerRows: 1,
          body: [
            [{ text: "Details", style: "tableHeader" }],

            [{ text: this.observableData }], // observable to pdf data not showing here.
          ],
        },
        layout: "lightHorizontalLines",
      },
    ],
  };

  this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefination);

  if (this.plt.is("cordova")) {
    this.pdfObj.getBase64(async (data) => {
      try {
        let path = `pdf/myletter_${Date.now()}.pdf`;

        const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path,
          data: data,
          directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
          recursive: true,
        });
        this.fileOpener.open(`${result.uri}`, "application/pdf");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Unable to write file: ", error);
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.pdfObj.download();
  }
}
```

Note: observableData is contain firebase documents value.

Comment: use. `JSON.parse(this.observableData)`

Comment: Argument of type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345) i get this error

Answer (score 0):

To get data from an observable, you need to subscribe:

```
this.observableData.subscribe(data => this.realData = data);
```

`realData` should contain needed data (probably you should additionally extract it in some way from the firebase document).

You should keep in mind that `subscribe` doesn't return data immediately. You can check the documentation about `Observables` and `Subscriptions`:

https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription

Comment: I have tried that way but that does not work it returns [object Object]. Though it shows in `consol.log(realData)` but not showing inside PDF.

Comment: @Ahmed You can extract from the `data` what you need and use it. Also, you can represent the whole object as a string: `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'
    |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'SubjectSubscription'
    --- property '_parentOrParents' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>) Got This Error with JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @Ahmed So... Check the structure of your `data` object in the console and extract the needed values.